# Microsoft Excel Power Query: Select columns that contain strings from a string list

Tags: excel, powerquery, excel-2016, m

**Background**

I have a dataset with 10,000+ variables as column headers, which I want to reduce to the amount needed. I know how to select a sample of columns by listing columns that contain manually specified strings, say "glu" and "pep", that the columns must contain in order to be selected. This is the M code used to select the sample columns:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="data"]}[Content],
    ColumnsToSelect = List.Select(Table.ColumnNames(Source), each Text.Contains(_, "glu") or Text.Contains(_, "pep")),
    SelectColumns = Table.SelectColumns(Source, ColumnsToSelect)    
in
    SelectColumns
```

This Power Query produces a table that i call "Data". Since I want to select columns based on multiple strings they must contain, I have made a dynamic list of strings that I have called ["Outcomes"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9NP7.png). I want my Power Query to utilize this list of strings when choosing what columns to select.

**Question**

Is it possible to get my Power Query to utilize this dynamic list in the List.Select() or Table.SelectColumns() function or any other function, that will make my Power Query select only the columns that contain the strings on the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use with this lines:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Data"]}[Content],

    Source2 = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Outcomes"]}[Content],
    Outcomes = Source2[Outcomes],

    UnpivotedColumns = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {}, "ColumnNames", "Filters"),

    FilteredRows = Table.SelectRows(UnpivotedColumns, each List.AnyTrue(List.Transform(Outcomes, (substring) => Text.Contains([Filters], substring)))),

    ColumnNames = List.Sort(List.Distinct(FilteredRows[ColumnNames]),Order.Ascending),
    SelectColumns = Table.SelectColumns(Source,ColumnNames)
in
    SelectColumns
```

the magic is in this line:

```
FilteredRows = Table.SelectRows(UnpivotedColumns, each List.AnyTrue(List.Transform(Outcomes, (substring) => Text.Contains([Filters], substring)))),
```

Comment: I can't seem to visualize how my dynamic list values are utilized by using those lines. I have a Power Query that produces a table called "Data". This Power Query needs to select columns that contain strings that are listed in a third party list called "Outcomes". The strings "glu" and "pep" is just some of the many strings present in the "Outcomes" list.

Comment: I see, I updated my answer now it works for Outcomes.

Comment: The only alteration i needed to make for it to suit my needs, was to change [Filters] with [ColumnNames], now it works perfectly! Having the information that the column that needs to contain the list strings can be the Filters column is very useful in the future though.